# Using SqlConnection to execute query in VS 2010 Debugger: Evaluation of expression or statement timed out

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I try to execute some SQL code in the VS 2010 debugger I get this error message:

**`Evaluation of expression or statement timed out`**

I am using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to execute my queries on SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there a way to tell the Visual Studio debugger to wait until my query returns so I can see the result of the query in the debugger?

Comment: How exactly are you executing it? Does that API have a timeout you can tweak? (for example, DbCommand has a CommandTimeout)

Comment: Can you show us the  _"SQL code in the VS 2008 debugger"_? Are you using ADO
.NET?

Comment: Marc. The timeout is set to default. All SQL code runs fine when outside the debugger. Just doesn't run in the debugger - times out.